# jQuery slideshow not working when loaded onto the page with jQuery's .load() method

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, slideshow

everyone. I'm quite new to jQuery and WordPress, so please be kind :)

My question pertains to this site, which I'm making for a friend's band: http://ecbiz119.inmotionhosting.com/~fullbo6/

They want the user to be able to click around the site while the music plays. So I'm trying to use jQuery's .load() method to asynchronously load content from other pages. (Not ideal, I know, but it's the best I could come up with.)

The slideshow on the home page seems fine when the page initially loads. When it reloads, though, the animation skips. I've searched high and low for a solution, but no luck.

Here's the code used to make the slideshow work:

```
$('#slide-show > li:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $('#slide-show > li:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slide-show');
}, 5000);
```

When the user clicks on any link that is NOT the home link, the following code executes. (The reference to 'jspPane' is the jScrollPane plugin that makes the content div scrollable):

```
$('#main-nav').not('.page-item-6').find('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#main-nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#slide-show-container, #updates-wrap .container').empty();
    $('.jspPane').empty().load(href + ' .page-content');
    $('#page-content-container').show();
});
```

And when the home link is clicked, the following code executes (it's basically just the above, but in reverse):

```
$('#main-nav .page-item-6').find('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#main-nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#slide-show-container').load(href + ' #slide-show');
    $('#page-content-container').hide();
});
```

Thanks in advance for any insight anyone can offer. I really appreciate it!

UPDATE: Here is the full code now.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

startSlideShow();

function startSlideShow(){
    $('#slide-show > li:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function() {    
        $('#slide-show > li:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slide-show');
    },  5000);
}


$('#page-content-container').jScrollPane().hide();

$('#main-nav .page-item-6 a').addClass('active');

$('#main-nav').not('.page-item-6').find('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#main-nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#slide-show-container, #updates-wrap .container').empty().hide();
    $('.jspPane').empty().load(href + ' .page-content');
    $('#page-content-container').show();
});

$('#main-nav .page-item-6').find('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#main-nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#slide-show-container').load(href + ' #slide-show', function(){
            startSlideShow();   
    });
    $('#slide-show-container, #updates-wrap .container').show();
    $('#page-content-container').hide();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call the method which does the slideshow after the load is completed ?

```
$('.jspPane').empty().load(href + ' .page-content',function(){
    StartSlideShow();   

});
```

and in your StartSlideShow method, have the code for the slide show

```
function StartSlideShow()
{
  // Code for the slide show
}
```

Comment: Thanks, CAbbott! That helped part of the problem. No more skipping. But when it reloads, the slideshow appears to go at double the speed.

Comment: @BrianO'Neill : Make sure you have only one instance of slide show running. or check the inteval timeout variable value.